# delete updates to trigger for same fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am working on some legacy code that performs updates on a specific row one field at a time.  The way the history works is that  all the fields are written each time an update, insert, or delete occurs.  How do I eliminate all but the last update within a specific orderId, a small time interval, and the same userid if after the trigger finished an insert into my history table?

```
delete from tblHistory as h 
where h.OrderId in 
      (SELECT OrderId 
       from inserted 
       where datediff("s",myDate, getdate() ) <= 5) 
               and exists (select b.* 
                            FROM   inserted as b 
                            WHERE b.userId = h.userId and 
                             b.OrderId = h.orderId)  -- except last one 
                                                                              -- within last 1 to 5 seconds
```

My tblHistory has HistoryId as an auto incrementing primary key.  So I should have two or more HistoryIds but only one OrderId and the date diff needs to be within at least 5 seconds.  I want to make sure my history isn't overflowing as we only have limited space for tracking history. 
Also I only wanto to scrunch the data only if the userId is the same as well.

Comment: I need to delete this where historyId is less than the newest historyId.

Comment: The OrderId is also being recorded in the OrderHistory table, but OrderHistoryId is the auto incrementing feature of this table.

Comment: I think I figured this out, I can do this after the updates are finished,  After waiting, I can delete the history row if it is less than an existing history row's OrderHistoryId and all of the criteria above also matches. thx

Comment: Without running the delete statement, I can't tell if it would work, but it looks good.  I would put it in the trigger before your insert so then it will delete any prior entries and just leave the one you are about to write.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the logic in use here, but I would suggest to switch around the `DateDiff()` so the function doesn't need to recalculate for every single record but instead can lock on the GetDate() 'constant'. In this case, that would mean you'd rather use `WHERE myDate >= DateAdd(s, -5, GetDate())`.

Answer (score 1):

I am questioning why you would want to delete these records - and if you have to do it, I am questioning why you are doing it inside the trigger. I'd prefer a solution the reduces the data on a daily basis.
But if you really have to do it, this could work:

```
delete h
from   tblHistory h
inner join inserted i
  on   i.OrderId = h.OrderId
  and  i.UserId = h.UserId
where  h.MyDate > dateadd("s",-5,getdate())
  and  h.HistoryID <
       (select max(h2.HistoryID)
       from    tblHistory h2
       where   h2.OrderId = i.OrderId);
```

I considered that it is possible to insert more than one row at a time resulting in more the one record in inserted.
In the end it should delete max. one record per execution.
You could need indexes on (OrderId, HistoryId) and (OrderId, UserId, MyDate) for good performance.

HTH

Comment: I have no idea why I would have even wrote this. I must have been drunk or trying to figure out something for another drunk or drugged software engineer.